# Scan qr code, pass the qr content in to query and display the result on screen in android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am using zxing to scan qr code in android and getting the result. Now I want to pass the qr code content (which is always a number) into sqlite select query and display the result on to the screen. But when I pass the content into the query, i am getting Null pointer Exception.
The code is

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
  intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contentId = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");                

            Cursor cursorDetails = db.query("cd_details", new String[] {"location","latitude","longitude","photo"}, "id" + " = " + "'" + contentId + "'", null, null, null, null);
            cursorDetails.moveToFirst();


        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {                
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Scan was Cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
            toast.show();                
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error in the query line. The error reads like this

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.pixel.scanner/com.pixel.scanner.ScannerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.pixel.scanner/com.pixel.scanner.ScannerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2124)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1672)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:939)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.pixel.scanner/com.pixel.scanner.ScannerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
... 13 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.pixel.scanner.ScannerActivity.onActivityResult(ScannerActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
... 14 more
```

Line 70 in the above code is

```
Cursor cursorDetails = db.query("cd_details", new String[] {"location","latitude","longitude","photo"}, "id" + " = " + "'" + contentId + "'", null, null, null, null);
```

Any suggestions on this one will be a great help.

Comment: At ScannerActivity line 70, you have a null object.

Comment: @bmavus thanks for the reply. But I don't have any null objects there.

Comment: @bmavus check my edited question. I have mentioned line 70.

Comment: At Emulator's settings go Developer Options and check "Don't keep activities" is checked. I think your application dies before result reach.

Comment: This is an interesting error. I typed "android Failure delivering result ResultInfo" to google. There is many people get this exception, but there is no proper answer. Create a new emulator and try your application on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace already tells you the answer. Your app has a problem on line 70. `db` is null.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got a clue from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I din't open the database for READ/WRITE. So db was coming null. I added the below line and its working now..

```
  db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(fileIsExists.toString(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```